# Aggregation in same row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need some help with performing an aggregation.
I have the following statement:

```
SELECT name,
CASE WHEN year=2013 THEN count(ID) END AS 'Count2013',
CASE WHEN year=2012 THEN count(ID) END AS 'Count2012'
FROM Table GROUP BY year, name
```

and get the results as follows:

```
Name    Count2013        Count2012
ABC     NULL             14731
ABC     456              NULL
DEF     NULL             5666
DEF     14439            NULL
```

How can I get the following results?

```
Name    Count2013    Count2012
ABC     456          14731
DEF     14439        5666
```

Note, that I am trying to display results in same row without `NULL`.

Comment: Correlated Subqueries?  `(Select ... From ... Where ... ) as CustomCol`?

Comment: @g.d.d.c - No need to hit the table more than once. Just need to use some conditions. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use a case expression.

```
SELECT name
    , sum(CASE WHEN year = 2013 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Count2013'
    , sum(CASE WHEN year = 2012 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Count2012'
FROM Table GROUP BY name
```